# Add new Component on componentDidMount in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, components

I need to calculate the width of the component before rendering child component.

But, problem is that I need to render components first to be able to get width which is needed for child component.

In other words, I need to prepend child component after render is finished in main component.

I guess that **`componetnDidMount()`** is best for do that.

this is code example

```
/**
 * @returns void
 */
componentDidMount()
{
    let width = this.seatMap.offsetWidth;
    // I want to add component here
    <LeafletMap width={width}/>
}

/**
 * @returns {XML}
 */
render() {
    return (
        <div className="SeatMap" ref={seatMap => { this.seatMap = seatMap } }>
            // This is way how it is work at this moment
            <LeafletMap />
            </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, add state variables in your constructor. One for checking if LeafletMap is ready to be rendered, and other for width of LeafletMap to be passed as prop:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        widthLeafletMap: null
        displayLeafletMap: false
    };
}
```

Then, in your `componentDidMount` method, update both of these state variables to re-render the parent component as you now know the width for `LeafletMap` and it is ready to be displayed:

```
componentDidMount()
{
    let width = this.seatMap.offsetWidth;
    this.setState({
        widthLeafletMap: width,
        displayLeafletMap: true
    });
}
```

Finally, update your `render()` method to display LeafletMap component when it is ready to be displayed with the desired width (if only `displayLeafletMap` is `true`, it will display it with desired width):

```
render() {
    let displayLeafletMap = this.state.displayLeafletMap;
    let widthLeafletMap = this.state.widthLeafletMap;
    return (
        <div className="SeatMap" ref={seatMap => { this.seatMap = seatMap } }>
            {displayLeafletMap && (
                <div className="row">
                    <LeafletMap width={widthLeafletMap} />
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

we can set the state in componentDidMount and check the state in the render so only when the component did mount and the state is set so you can return , something like:

```
/**
 * @returns void
 */
... define state in constructor ...

componentDidMount()
{
    let width = this.seatMap.offsetWidth;
    // set state here
    this.setState({seatMapWidth: width});
}

/**
 * @returns {XML}
 */
render() {
//add condition here to control your return 
  const {seatMapWidth} = this.state;
  if(seatMapWidth !== null){
   // if this state is not null so return your component
     return <LeafletMap width={seatMapWidth}/> 
}
   return (
        <div className="SeatMap" ref={seatMap => { this.seatMap = seatMap } }>
            // This is way how it is work at this moment
            <LeafletMap />
            </div>
    );
}
```